# Converting xml into Soap Request

Tags: java, xml, soap

I want to convert xml as a String into soap request, but this xml doesn't include envelope , I tried this

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

public class TestSoapConverter {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String message="<ISO8583PostXml>"+
                "<MsgType>0300</MsgType>"+
                "<Fields>"+
                "<field_001>080000</field_001>"+
                "<field_0090>000000</field_0090>"+
                "<field_048>0822074323</field_048>"+
                "<field_020>94</field_020>"+
                "<field_080>0822</field_080>"+
                "</Fields>"+
                "</ISO8583PostXml>";

        try{

    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage   soapMessage = factory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(),
                new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
          System.out.println(soapMessage.getSOAPBody());

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   
}
```

I got this Exception

> May 23, 2017 8:14:08 PM
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl lookForEnvelope
>   SEVERE: SAAJ0514: Unable to create envelope from given source because
>   the root element is not named Envelope May 23, 2017 8:14:08 PM
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory
>   createEnvelope SEVERE: SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given
>   source com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable
>   to create envelope from given source:     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:128)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(MessageImpl.java:1351)
>     at
>   com.vericash.liquid.test.TestSoapConverter.main(TestSoapConverter.java:30)
>   Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element
>   is not named "Envelope"   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.lookForEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:154)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:110)
>     ... 4 more
>
> CAUSE:
>
> com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to
>   create envelope from given source because the root element is not
>   named "Envelope"  at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.lookForEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:154)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:110)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:128)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(MessageImpl.java:1351)
>     at
>   com.vericash.liquid.test.TestSoapConverter.main(TestSoapConverter.java:30)

Comment: The code is failing due to the namespace schema not matching your xml.  The schena requires the root xml tag name to be "Envelope".  If you can locate the namespace webpage you can go to the webpage using an IE and see the schema.